# Background image disappears after navigating back and forth several times React native

Tags: react-native, imageview

I have made a simple view with a background image and some icons on top of it. Clicking on icons navigate to different pages. It is working fine. Problem is when I navigate to other pages come back to home page and do this for 7-8 times the background image just disappears from all the screens. Below is the code of home screen and Screenshots

```
  <Image
  source={require('../images/background.jpg')}
  style={{
    justifyContent:'center',                                                       
    resizeMode: "stretch",
    height: height,
    width: width,
    alignItems: "center"
  }} >
  <StatusBar
  backgroundColor="#4e0870"
  barStyle="light-content"

/>
<Image style={{ height: 125, width: 125 }} source={require('../images/guru_logo.png')} />

<View style={{
  marginTop: 30,
  flexDirection: 'row'
}}>
  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    navigate("LiveTV")
  }
  }
  >
    <Image
      source={require('../images/live.png')}
      style={{
        resizeMode: "stretch",
        height: 75,
        width: 75
      }} /></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    navigate("VideoPage")
  }}>

    <Image
      source={require('../images/youtube.png')}
      style={{
        marginTop: 5,

        resizeMode: "stretch",
        marginLeft: 100,
        height: 75,
        width: 75
      }} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
<View

  style={{

    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20
  }}>
  <Text
    style={{
      marginLeft: -5,
      fontSize: 20,
      color: "#FFF"
    }}>Live Tv</Text>
  <Text
    style={{
      fontSize: 20,
      color: "#FFF",
      marginLeft: 125
    }}>Video</Text>
</View>
<View
  style={{

    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20
  }}>
  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    navigate("FacebookPage")
  }}>
    <Image
      source={require('../images/facebook-logo.png')}
      style={{
        resizeMode: "stretch",
        height: 75,
        width: 75
      }} /></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    navigate("AudioPage")
  }}>
    <Image
      source={require('../images/icon.png')}
      style={{
        resizeMode: "stretch",
        marginLeft: 100,
        height: 75,
        width: 75
      }} /></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
<View
  style={{

    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20
  }}>
  <Text
    style={{
      marginLeft: -20,
      fontSize: 20,
      color: "#FFF"
    }}>Facebook</Text>

  <Text
    style={{
      fontSize: 20,
      color: "#FFF",
      marginLeft: 110
    }}>Audio</Text>
</View>

<TouchableOpacity  activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  navigate("ContactPage")
}}>
  <Image
    source={require('../images/contact.png')}
    style={{


      marginTop: 20,
      resizeMode: "stretch",
      height: 75,
      width: 75
    }} /></TouchableOpacity>
<Text style={{
  fontSize: 20,
  color: "#FFF"
}}>Contact Us</Text>
</Image>
```

[image: invisible view]
[image: Normal view]

Comment: Not sure but some times it happens while testing in emulator, try to create release build and then test for the same . If issue still persist, you need to check for code / css .

Comment: I am already using release build and testing on device

Comment: Are you using webpack by chance?

Comment: I am not aware about webpack

Comment: I think the problem is with providing a relative path. I had this issue as well 
and I solved it by changing my image imports to a path not dependent on your directory structure const image = '/assets/images/myimage.png'; Then in my webpack (which is the development server too i use) configuration I specify   publicPath: /assets/ and path: path.resolve(APP_PATH, 'assets'). You might need to look into how your server is configured and how it's serving static files.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you navigate to that screen, it calls a re-render. I work around i've found in the past is to define your image sources as a variable, and simply reference it in the `source = {HERE}` section. I've provided some sample code below. This has fixed this issue in the past, let me know how it goes.

```
var images = {
    live: {img: require('../images/live.png')},
    guru: {img: require('../images/guru_logo.png')},
    background: {img: require('../images/background.jpg')},
    //and so on 
}

class SelectionScreen extends Component {
    //all your other code
```

and then in your `Image` components

```
<Image source = {images[background].img}.../>
```

Comment: Let me try and I will get back to you

Comment: It is throwing an error, can't find variable background

Comment: It accessed it using images.background.img, because it is not an array, But still it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be related to this react-native issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13600

I would try to:

- Run the app on different phones / emulators to see if it depends on
  device specifications (like RAM and others). If the app is for both Android and iOS I would also try to see if it's same behaviour on both platforms;
- Replace temporary the images with some other smaller/larger images to see if it changes somehow the issue;
- Upgrade React Native if necessary and use [BackgroundImage](https://medium.com/@hklucher/how-to-use-an-imagebackground-in-react-native-515ee06a6b1f) component for background images instead of Image.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: @Billa, Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to write comments on other people's posts.